# Get new contents of a file

Tags: node.js, file-io, maxima

A node.js script calls the maxima computer algebra system and redirects my input to the `stdin` of maxima. Maxima the writes the processed input to a temporary text file where there is a new line for every result maxima returns.

Can node watch for new data written to the file and somehow capture this data (only the new line which is written to the file, not the whole file)?

I already tried `fs.watchFile` but was unable to capture the actual data returned by it.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't there a way to make Maxima output to its stdout?

Comment: Yes, by default Maxima outputs to stdout, but it adds a lot of clutter (like labels for each line of input/output) to the stream. Of course you would want that when using Maxima from the Terminal, but in my case, I just want to capture the TeX output which is easiest written to a file without all the extra info like labels.

Comment: Oh, so it can't be made to produce "clean" stdout output. It sounds to me like you could use a named pipe instead of a temporary file to get the semantics you want, but I've never actually used them.

Comment: I did some research on google and it seems that Maxima can only output to stdout or a file. But I have to admit that I'm relatively new to Unix-like operation systems. Of course I know how to redirect the output of a command to a file but neither do I know how to pipe outputs, nor do I know how to receive these pipes in node.js so I guess using a file as a temporary storage would be the simplest solution.

Comment: I mentioned named pipes because they look like regular files to other processes, with some caveats. My general idea was that you'd create a named pipe using [`mkfifo`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkfifo), then pass the filename of the pipe to Maxima instead of your temporary file. Then, from node.js, you'd open this file and attempt to read from it.

Comment: Depending on how Maxima writes to this temporary file, you'll have to keep opening the named pipe in a loop in node.js. When the writing end of a closed pipe closes its handle to it, reading from the pipe returns an EOF. (And of course there's still the possibility Maxima won't like the idea of writing to a special file.)

Comment: I think I got your idea now. The only problem I see is that the implementation of named pipes in node is relatively new and not documented yet. I also read that listening on a named pipe would somehow break the asynchronous event loop (I don't know how bad that is but it sounds like a bad practice). It is advised to use a unix socket instead. The pro here is that reading from that socket in node is quite easy, I just don't know how to create such a socket and wether it is possible to write to a socket like to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.watchFile` plugs in to the actual file watching functionality in your Operating System (inotify in Linux), it does nothing more than just routing these events through. Any logic on which lines has been changed etc. has to be implemented by yourself. As it's a log file you probably are only interested in the tail, and you can reuse other programs for that. See [this example](http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2009/12/7/real-time-online-activity-monitor-example-with-node-js-and-websocket) for instance.

If you want to roll your own just do something like:

```
fs.watchFile("/path/to/log.txt", function (prev, curr) {
    // verify writes
    if (x && y && z) {
        fs.readFile("/path/to/log.txt", "utf8", function (err, body) {
             // check what has been appended
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So basically this means I have to check wether the file has changed or not using the 'fs.watchFile', if it changed, I get the data that has been appended and pass it on to my other logic. Another solution which has been suggested to me is to use a UNIX domain socket. Maybe you can verify (since you seem to be a linux user) wether or not I can write to a UNIX socket like I would write to a file? Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, watchFile doesn't give you that much information. If you are just interested in appended lines, then check the link I referenced. It shows how to do analyzing on logfiles using node.js & tail.

Comment: What do you think about the performance of this method? In my test, it took about 3-4 seconds for 'fs.watchFile' to fire the callback. I would like to use this during a request from the web and it would be really annoying if it took 5 seconds and more to get the results to the browser.

Comment: Mac OS Lion 10.7.2. I did some testing yesterday without your suggested solution (using tail) and it took quite long.

Comment: Hmm... I'm on Lion too. I will ask for some info from one of the node devs.

Comment: It turns out I don't even need to use watchFile. 'tail -f' does exactly what I need. Thank you for your kind help!